# I don't have Intel Virtualization Technology in BIOS

Tags: android, intel, processor

I am trying to install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator in Android Studio.
I can't finish the installation because it says that i must enable Intel Virtualization Technology.

I googled a bit and found out that it can be enabled in BIOS, but i can't find such option in BIOS.

I have ASUS K53-SM with Windows 7 x64, Intel Core i7-2670QM.

What can I do, update BIOS or?

Thank you!

Comment: That CPU certainly supports the virtualization extensions. Sometimes, in the BIOS, the virtualization extensions are referred to as VT-x -- if you see an option for that, enable it.

Comment: No such option in bios...
Under Advanced i have Intel AES-NI which is enabled.
I have UEFI Boot and PXE ROM under Boot, but i think that's not interesting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try running some commands as admin from within windows
 - bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
- bcdedit /set nx AlwaysOn
Also make sure you have Avast off or disable "Enable hardware-assisted virtualization" under: Settings > Troubleshooting)
Then reboot.